# How to grant access to AWS Lambda in Python to read external web pages?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to read an external API using AWS Lambda (written in Python) but it fails. It seems the problem is related to access and permissions.

(module initialization error: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden)

Thanks for your guidance in advance.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = "https://api.x.com/v1/x.json"
response = urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
```

Comment: If you go to that URL from your own web browser, what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an https connection, then you should not face any problem.
To check if your external API is working, create a new lambda function and try to call API from there. Run tests and post results here. For more reference, please refer to this link
[Invoking REST API from within lambda function](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/95692/invoking-a-rest-api-from-within-a-lambda-function.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I used the https connection, as I showed in the code. Running the above scripts generates the following result:

`Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "module initialization error"
}`

The log message that I receive it quite similar:

`module initialization error: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found the error. The problem was the API didn't work without agent-key. It works when I imitate a web-browser by providing headers. Thanks a lot!